# Computer randomly turning off after BIOS update?

Tags: bios, power-supply, power, shutdown

I recently built a new PC, which has been running fine up until a BIOS update yesterday.

I normally wouldn't update BIOS unless there were issues and in this particular case, the AMD FX-6100 CPU I'd ordered wouldn't run CS:GO without a BIOS update... made the update, game works perfectly, all is well.

Now, randomly, the computer will just completely turn off. No 'proper' shut-down, no BSOD, just an instant power-off. It does appear to be entirely random, not when the computer is doing anything demanding or otherwise.

It's relatively frequent, it's rare that the PC can be used for longer than 30 mins without it doing this.

The BIOS is the only thing that's changed since it started happening. I've tried updating the BIOS with progressively older versions with the same result. After the computer turns off, the only way to turn it back on is to turn off the PC at the PSU switch for 5-10 seconds, turn it back on then start up as usual.

Temperatures are all normal, so it's not like the CPU is overheating and shutting down - as I said, the machine doesn't necessarily have to be doing anything demanding, could just be sat at the desktop.

Windows event viewer just shows a critical 'Kernel-Power' issue, as you'd expect but doesn't give anything else away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your graphic card require power? How powerful is your PSU? (+1 for a good clear question). It is possible it's not the BIOS update per se, but a graphic card conflict!

Comment: Hi Dave, GPU does not require 6-pin (or any other) power, just PCI-e. IIRC the PSU is 500w, which by my calculations should be more than sufficient. It was a cheap PSU though. I've been doing more googling and it looks like someone was having similar issues that were resolved by fiddling with AMD's Cool n Quiet setting in the BIOS and the Windows power plan, so that will be my first point of call when I can get back in front of the computer.

Comment: Will update the question with progress, or answer it myself with steps taken if the issue is resolved. This kind of issue seems to be fairly widespread, though a solution isn't.

Comment: **Does the computer shut down in the same manner if you let it sit in the BIOS setup, or the Windows boot menu, from a power cycle?** The idea would be to reduce the amount of code running and the amount of code having had a chance to touch the system state, and see if the problem persists. If you see the same behavior in the BIOS setup, it's likely hardware- or BIOS-related; if not, something the OS or an application does is more likely causing this.

Comment: Hi Michael, I haven't had the problem when in the BIOS setup or using Q-Flash, but haven't spent a great deal of time in there. Will let it sit there for a while and report back. Thanks.